# md-tab-body outside of md-tabs

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I'm using the `md-tabs` but I would like the content, that is what is stated in `md-tab-body`, you can somehow declare outside. For example:

```
<md-tabs ...>
    <md-tab>
        <md-tab-label>Tab 1</md-tab-label>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab>
        <md-tab-label>Tab 2</md-tab-label>
    </md-tab>
    <md-tab>
        <md-tab-label>Tab 3</md-tab-label>
    </md-tab>
</md-tabs>
<div layout="row">
    <div flex="50">
        <md-tab-body>Body for md-tab 1</md-tab-body>
        <md-tab-body>Body for md-tab 2</md-tab-body>
        <md-tab-body>Body for md-tab 3</md-tab-body>
    </div>
    <div class="map" flex="50">...</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to do this? Also the not separate, but I wish the `md-tab-body` is divided with a div in common, in this case `div.map`.

Comment: did u find a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I too had similar requirement but i couldn't find a direct solution, but this is how i did.

### in view

```
<md-tabs ...>
<md-tab md-on-select="selectTab('md-tab-1')">
    <md-tab-label>Tab 1</md-tab-label>
</md-tab>
<md-tab md-on-select="selectTab('md-tab-2')">
    <md-tab-label>Tab 2</md-tab-label>
</md-tab>
<md-tab md-on-select="selectTab('md-tab-3')">
    <md-tab-label>Tab 3</md-tab-label>
</md-tab>
</md-tabs>
<div layout="row">
<div flex="50">
    <md-tab-body ng-Show="isSelected('md-tab-1')">Body for md-tab 1</md-tab-body>
    <md-tab-body ng-Show="isSelected('md-tab-2')">Body for md-tab 2</md-tab-body>
    <md-tab-body ng-Show="isSelected('md-tab-3')">Body for md-tab 3</md-tab-body>
</div>
<div class="map" flex="50">...</div>
</div>
```

### in controller

```
$scope.selectedTab = 'md-tab-1';

$scope.selectTab = function(tab) {
$scope.selectedTab = tab;
}

$scope.isSelected = function(tab) {
return tab === $scope.selectedTab;
}
```

You can also map each tab to a route/controller and load your content dynamically by following the above example.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no no way. However you can use `md-selected="data.selectedIndex"` and something like `ui-view/ng-view` depending on how you manage your views. Track the tab index and change views.